# CSS styling of nested divs

Tags: css

I want to make table using divs. I nested divs in this manner:

```
<div class='table'>
        <div class='row'>
                <div class='cell'>
                </div>
                ...
                ...
        </div>
</div>
```

I change width of each div and not everything changes as expected.

Changing width of table div behaves just fine.

Table width set to 70%:

[image]

Table width set to 80%:
[image]

Changing width of row div does nothing.

Row width set to 70%:
[image]

Row width set to 100%:

[image]

Changing width of cell div behaves totally unexpected.

Cell width set to 30%:
[image]

Cell width set to 20%:
[image]

Cell width set to 7%:
[image]

I tried including position: relative, didn't change anything.

Relevant css code is:

```
.table{


}

.heading{
    display: table-row;

}

.row{
    display: table-row;

}

.cell{

    display: table-cell;
    border: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    padding-left: 5px;

}
```

I change width of each class through Firefox's Dev tools.

Can you help me understand underlying logic?

Comment: "I want to make table using divs." Why?

Comment: I agree with you, <table> is for that purpose but I want to learn styling principles of CSS, so this is just for a education purposes.

Comment: Using the wrong element and trying to fix it with CSS is not a good way to learn how to do things.  Use the right element and be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table class needs css of:

```
display:table;
```

**Additional Info:**

**Table Width:** Changing the table width will make the entire table whatever size you specify, unless the content within is larger than what you've set it to. Cells will auto resize to fit the width.

**Row Width:** Does nothing. You aren't supposed to set a width on rows because they always take up 100% of the table width.

**Cell Width:** These need to always add up to 100% to work predictably. For example, if you have four cells per row, then you can set them to 25% width. Setting them all to 15% width doesn't make sense because 15*4=60... which leaves 40% unaccounted for.

You can, however, set a SINGLE cell's width to 15%, and then don't set any width for the remaining cells. At that point, the one you've set will always be 15%, and the rest will just take up the remaining space. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4g2Lavmy/4/

Comment: I added it, but it didn't solve the problem. Everything behaves in the same manner as before....

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/4g2Lavmy/  Is this what you were expecting?

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I'm afraid I didn't make my question clear enough. Why changing of width property in .row class changes nothing? And why changing of width property in .cell class make "unpredictable" changes to the table? What I want to finally accomplish is that one column takes for example 15% of the table... (But I also want to understand underlying logic, at the moment why things happen this way)

Comment: Ok, I've added more explanation. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Add the class name "cell" to all the div's which are inside the div.table and use CSS like this:

```
div.cell{width:30%;}
```